# route command not being executed in rc.local

Tags: linux, fedora

I tried adding `route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0` to my Fedora `rc.local` file, but it's not being executed when Fedora boots up. What can I do to fix this?

update:
i changed to the full path cmd in my rc.local /sbin/route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0 but its not being executed. I change it to sudo /sbin/route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0 it still doesnt work although it works when i manually enter it in the terminal.

Comment: I have been working over it and it looks the executing sequence is not as it should be, since systemd like to up system quickly it does not bother about if network service is up or not (specially in case of route adding). I am facing same problem but going to try loading rc-local.service after the network service.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the step by step configuration:

### Step 1

In /etc create symbolic link

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root         18 Jun 29 19:08 rc.local -> /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

In /etc/rc.d create rc.local file

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/route add -net 192.xxx.xx.x netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.xxx.xx.xx
```

Make rc.local executable, your rc.local file should look like

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root    93 Jul  4 18:30 rc.local
```

### Step 2

```
cd /lib/systemd/system
ls -l rc-local.service

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 565 Jul  6 20:18 rc-local.service
```

Edit rc-local.service, your rc-local.service file should look like as under:

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/etc/rc.d/rc.local
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/rc.local start
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes
SysVStartPriority=99
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add full path to route command, `/sbin/route add` should work.

Comment: Always use the full path for any commands in scripts. During part of the boot the $PATH is not yet set. in cron files your $PATH will also be diferent from your normal login.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, `rc.local` simply is not being executed at boot.  You can verify this by running `systemctl status rc-local.service`.  If it was not executed, you'll see output like this:

```
rc-local.service - /etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility
          Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static)
          Active: inactive (dead)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/rc-local.service
```

If it was executed successfully at boot, you'll instead see output like this:

```
rc-local.service - /etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility
          Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static)
          Active: active (exited) since Sun, 01 Apr 2012 12:54:47 -0700; 1 day and 21h ago
        Main PID: 380 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/rc-local.service
```

If it's not being executed a boot, you've likely hit a common pitfall.  Traditionally, Red Hat systems placed this file in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, with a symlink at `/etc/rc.local` for people familiar with Debian systems.  Recent versions of Fedora do not include the `rc.local` file by default, to speed up boot slightly by not having to execute `bash` on what is on most systems an empty file.  `systemd` now checks to see whether `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` exists and is executable, and only executes it if it is.

If you created the file at `/etc/rc.local`, you'll need to move or symlink it to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` for it to be executed on boot.  You should also verify that it is executable, (`chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local`).